# Ionic4 Firebase Taking too long to load data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, chat, ionic4

I have created an ionic chat application with firebase realtime database. However, when I am trying to load all the users (around 150 for now) for "Add new user" page, it is taking too long to load all my data. Below are my files:

**all-users.page.html**

```html
<ion-list lines="none" no-padding *ngIf="accounts && (accounts.length > 1)">
    <ion-searchbar mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchUser" animated type="search"
        placeholder="Search"></ion-searchbar>
    <div *ngFor="let account of accounts | userFilter:searchUser">
        <ion-item button=true detail=false lines="none" type="button" (click)="startMessage(account.key)">
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
            <img src="{{account.photoURL}}" onError="this.src='/assets/img/default-dp.png'">
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
            <h2>{{account.fullName}}</h2>
            <p class="emailCustom">{{ account.email }}</p>
        </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

**all-users.page.ts**

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.showLoading();
    this.accountsInfoResSub = this.getData.getUsers().snapshotChanges().subscribe((accountsInfoRes) => {
        let acc = accountsInfoRes.filter((c: any) => {
        if (c.key == null && c.key == undefined && c.payload.val() == null) return false;
        if (c.payload.val().fullName == '' || c.payload.val().fullName == ' ' || c.payload.val().fullName == undefined) return false;
        if (c.payload.val().publicVisibility == false) return false;
        return true;
        });
        this.accounts = acc.map((c: any) => {
        return { key: c.key, ...c.payload.val() }
        });
        console.log(this.accounts);
    });
}
```

**user-filter.pipe.ts**

```js
export class UserFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  transform(accounts: any, term?: any): any {
    if (!accounts) {
      return;
    } else if (!term) {
      console.log(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
      return accounts.filter((account) => account.uid != this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
    } else {
      term = term.toLowerCase();
      return accounts.filter((account) => (account.uid != this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid) && account.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1);
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here. I do get all my users listed but it is taking like 5-10 seconds to load 150 records.

Comment: This is not about the number of records, this is about the amount of data (size). Maybe each user has 1MB of information? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @TheUnreal: This is how my single data record fetched looked like: {
        "key":"iEDzVD1YTIeSgsfT6ZYfY8im5SKtV2",
        "email":"adaxxxxball@gmail.com",
        "fullName":"Ad Ball",
        "myid":"150308",
        "nickName":"ad","pushToken":"cYsam5w5GOI:APA91bGuQuIvFHZL8Bb-sxFiMPF57KSmwQUEHaWdqaynJG2TtBQaGzz3EF1xRuyF_GqG2KheetJkghVrGE48-MrX2xrydKn6iZKIotPGTZPQhY1rt7_j1kSf_HrxW8R0zS9Fe3gkDceo1",
        "uid":"iEDzVD1YTIeSgxdT6ZYfY8im5SKtV2"
    }

Comment: I am just fetching general user information of each user registered in my app to show them up in the chat users list.

Comment: How long is the network elapsed time (from request to response) of the firebase user query? Check out the network tab in the developer console, there's a 'timings' sub-tab that should give you that info.